# Let M be a matching and let C be a vertex cover in a graph G. Prove that |M| $\le$ |C|.

Tags: graph-theory

I have to prove that |M| $\le$ |C|.

The proof that my partner has come with is:
Let M' be a maximum matching of G and let C' be a minimum vertex cover. For any edge, E, in M' there exists an endpoint of E in C'. Thus because the edges of M' share no endpoints, |M| $\le$ |M'| $\le$ |C'| $\le$ |C|. Therefore |M| $\le$ |C|.

How can I improve this?

Comment: It's fine, but there is no need to talk about a maximum matching $M^\prime$ and a minimum vertex cover $C^\prime$. You can just apply the argument directly to $M$ and $C$.

Comment: So I would just put let M be a matching in G and let C be a vertex cover. For any edge, E, in M there exists an endpoint of E in C. Thus because the edges of M share no endpoints, |M| ≤ |C|.

Comment: Yes that's enough.